# Backprop neural network learns simple functions but doesn't learn sklearn iris dataset

Tags: python, neural-network

I've written a backpropagation neural network in Python using NumPy for the matrix calculations and batch updating. It learns binary functions like XOR well, but when I train it on the the `iris` dataset (in `sklearn.datasets`) with one-vs-all (my target function is `y = iris.target == 1`) it settles on putting all 1's or all -1's on the outputs. I've tried learning rates in [0.01, 5], hidden-layer sizes in [3, 20] nodes, and up to 50k epochs with no improvement.

Below is the important code for the NN. `_sigmoid` is numpy's tanh function, and `_dsigmoid` is its derivative. I'd really appreciate any help!

```
def __init__(self, n_input, n_hidden, n_output):
    self.n_input = n_input + 1
    self.n_hidden = n_hidden
    self.n_output = n_output
    self.w1 = np.random.normal(scale=0.7, size=(self.n_input*self.n_hidden)).reshape(self.n_input, self.n_hidden)
    self.w2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.7, size=(self.n_hidden*self.n_output)).reshape(self.n_hidden, self.n_output)
    self.output_activation = np.zeros(n_output)
    self.hidden_activation = np.zeros(n_hidden)
    self.input_activation = np.zeros(n_input)

def feed_forward(self):
    """
    Update output vector created by feed-forward propagation of input activations
    """
    self.hidden_activation = self._sigmoid(np.dot(self.input_activation, self.w1))
    self.output_activation = self._sigmoid(np.dot(self.hidden_activation, self.w2))

def back_propagate(self, target, alpha):        
    output_error = target - self.output_activation
    output_delta = output_error * self._dsigmoid(self.output_activation)

    hidden_error = np.dot(output_delta, self.w2.T)
    hidden_delta = hidden_error * self._dsigmoid(self.hidden_activation)

    self.w2 += alpha * (np.dot(self.hidden_activation.T, output_delta))
    self.w1 += alpha * (np.dot(self.input_activation.T, hidden_delta))

def train(self, data, target, alpha, epochs=50):
    m = data.shape[0]

    # add bias to input
    X = np.ones((m, self.n_input))
    X[:, 1:] = data

    # turn target into a column vector
    target = target[:, np.newaxis]

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        self.input_activation = X
        self.feed_forward()
        self.back_propagate(target, alpha)

def predict(self, data):
    m = data.shape[0]
    self.input_activation = np.ones((m, self.n_input))
    self.input_activation[:, 1:] = data
    self.feed_forward()
    return self.output_activation
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```python
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets
import math

class NN():
    def __init__(self, n_input, n_hidden, n_output):
        self.n_input = n_input + 1
        self.n_hidden = n_hidden
        self.n_output = n_output
        self.w1 = np.random.normal(scale=0.7, size=(self.n_input*self.n_hidden)).reshape(self.n_input, self.n_hidden)
        self.w2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.7, size=(self.n_hidden*self.n_output)).reshape(self.n_hidden, self.n_output)
        self.output_activation = np.zeros(n_output)
        self.hidden_activation = np.zeros(n_hidden)
        self.input_activation = np.zeros(n_input)

    def _sigmoid(self,x):
        return(1/(1+math.e**(-x))) #sigmoid
        #return(np.tanh(x.astype(float))) #tanh

    def _dsigmoid(self,x):
        return(x*(1-x)) #sigmoid
        #return(1-x**2) #tanh

    def feed_forward(self):
        """
        Update output vector created by feed-forward propagation of input activations
        """
        self.hidden_activation = self._sigmoid(np.dot(self.input_activation, self.w1))
        self.output_activation = self._sigmoid(np.dot(self.hidden_activation, self.w2))

    def back_propagate(self, target, alpha):        
        output_error = (target - self.output_activation)
        output_delta = output_error * self._dsigmoid(self.output_activation)

        hidden_error = np.dot(output_delta, self.w2.T)
        hidden_delta = hidden_error * self._dsigmoid(self.hidden_activation)

        self.w2 += alpha * (np.dot(self.hidden_activation.T, output_delta))
        self.w1 += alpha * (np.dot(self.input_activation.T, hidden_delta))

    def train(self, data, target, alpha, epochs=50):
        m = data.shape[0]

        # add bias to input
        X = np.ones((m, self.n_input))
        X[:, 1:] = data

        # turn target into a column vector
        target = target[:, np.newaxis]

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.input_activation = X
            self.feed_forward()
            self.back_propagate(target, alpha)

    def predict(self, data):
        m = data.shape[0]
        self.input_activation = np.ones((m, self.n_input))
        self.input_activation[:, 1:] = data
        self.feed_forward()
        return self.output_activation

iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
data = iris['data']
targets = iris['target']
for i,t in enumerate(targets):
    if t!=1:
        targets[i] = 0
network = NN(4,3,1)
network.train(data,targets,0.01,epochs=10000)
print(network.predict(data))
print(targets)
```

I changed the function to sigmoid because it makes more sense when your targets are between 0 and 1. The problem might be in your data preparation or something else that you didn't share. Though, that seems unlikely because I could not get it to work with tanh and the results varied widely based on the number of hidden neurons. I think you should look at your back propagation code and maybe try gradient checking.